# How to store recording file names in database for Asterisk FreePBX

Tags: php, asterisk

How to store recording file names in database for Asterisk FreePBX ?

I am using FreePBX 2.6.0.5 and want to store the recording file names in the cdr table.
I have tried updating the "/etc/asterisk/cdr_mysql.conf" and set "userfield=1", also restarted the asterisk-- 
service asterisk restart

But there is no effect. Can anyone guide me in this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what you're saving the call recording filenames as. They are customisable. If its based on the "uniqueid" field in the CDR then be sure you have compiled MySQL to work with this as detailed here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cdr+mysql

Failing that you could alter the call recording file name - an example is given on the second post of this thread:

http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=76844&start=0

Answer (score 0):

While this wont help just yet, this feature is planned for inclusion in FreePBX 2.10.

UPDATE: This feature is in the new FreePBX 2.10

Comment: It would be nice if you explained how to enable it, since its available now